# Apply properties to every project you create in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++20

I'm trying to learn C++20 but I need to enable std:c++latest everytime I create a project in Visual Studio 2022.
Is there a way I can enable it for every project I create?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by using a .props file that enables modification for default values or create your own template project.

If you want to enable full modification use the .props file.
If not, use a new template.

Props file:
File path is usually in the directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props
```

or in VS2022:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props
```

Add for your desired condition or remove the condition:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
   <ClCompile>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpplatest</LanguageStandard>
   </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Read more in the docs to understand the project XML format:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-170

To add a template:
Create a Visual Studio project with your desired configuration.
Use the Export Wizard from `Projects>Export Template`

[image]

Comment: Alright, thank you, it worked but I also need "Compile As": /internalPartition and /experimental:module enabled.
If you could work it out it would be better if it was for all configurations and all platforms.

Comment: For the last part of my comment, do I just have to put the same thing more times with different configurations and platforms?

Comment: @HenkCoder You can remove the condition as I stated :) 
Or create your own conditions so if you need multiple choices based on configuration parameters.

For additional parameters just add them under the ItemDefinitionGroup.
You could separate them into different Groups but it doesn't matter unless the specific Condition matters.

Comment: Oh alright, what about how I can put "Compiler As": /internalPartition and /experimental:module always enabled? I have no idea for those but I managed to put std:c++latest to every configuration and platform.

Comment: Ok I managed to get /internalPartition done by adding this line to your code:
`<CompileAs>CompileAsCppModuleInternalPartition</CompileAs>` but I still need /experimental:module to work and I have no idea on how to work it out.
Could you help me out?

Comment: @HenkCoder

You can use ``<EnableModules>true</EnableModules>``

Best way to check is to edit an existing project and just copy the property :)

Comment: Ooooh alright, I didn't know that I could see other projects properties file, thank you very much, have a nice day :)